# GKGameCenterViewController Bug In IOS8

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8

Has anybody else suffered this - Loading GKGameCenterViewController on devices running IOS8 fails to return Game Center data or present Navigation Buttons for dismissing view.  Code is standard from Game Center Programming Guide and has worked for months on devices running IOS7.  Update IOS from 7 to 8 and BOOM!, the GKGameCenterViewController loads white transparent background only and no other content.  User is trapped in view with no Game Center data and no "Done" button to dismiss the view.  My app was released 5/14 and this happened when I updated iPad to IOS8 on Sep, 19th, 2014

Answer (score 3):

Looks like `GKGameCenterViewControllerStateDefault` is the culprit (a bug).  Add this prior to presenting the view:

```
gc.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also experiencing this issue since updating to iOS8. The workaround posted by dugbug seems to be incomplete - although information is displayed in the main tab with this workaround, the user is still not able to dismiss the game center view as the top bar navigation button to do this is replaced with a white area.

Comment: Adding the suggested line worked well in my App.  The "Done"  navigation button was also presented.  Thank you, Mureinik.  I hope your reputation rating increases.  Excellent!